# Receiving Firebase Dynamic Links only work on first install of app from App Store

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I am running into issues when attempting to receive dynamic links on iOS.

Specifically, it appears that receiving the info when tapping a dynamic link ONLY works when the app was freshly installed from the App Store after being redirected when tapping the dynamic link.

If the app is not installed on the device, the flow is the following:

1. Tap on a dynamic link (specifically from inside Notes app)
2. The app preview page is opened. The OPEN button is tapped with the "Save my place..." checked
3. The App Store page is opened
4. After downloading the app from the App Store and launching it, the dynamic link is handled as expected (opens the app to the specific view of the shared content)

However, any future taps on dynamic links have the following, unexpected flow:

1. Tap on a dynamic link (specifically from inside Notes app)
2. The app preview page is opened. The OPEN button is tapped with the "Save my place..." checked
3. The App Store page is opened

I am not sure why I am being redirected to the App Store instead of the app when it is installed on the device.

When tapping on a dynamic link with the app already installed (from the App Store) I was expecting to be taken directly to the app, and not the App Store.

If I install the app directly to my device (not through the App Store), then tapping on any dynamic link works as expected (takes me to a view of the shared content inside the app)

I have tried both using the standard app.page.link url as well as a fully custom url and the behavior is the same.

The `domain/apple-app-site-association` returns what looks to be correct data for both the default and custom domain
`{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"TEAMID.my.bundle.id","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}`

The associated domains were set up accordingly, as well as the `FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains` entries in the `Info.plist` (when testing the custom url)

I have used the self diagnostic tool:
`[FIRDynamicLinks performDiagnosticsWithCompletion:nil];`

Both scenarios (default url, and custom url) report that no problems were detected.

I have added the debug parameter to my links (`?d=1`) and no warnings are reported

Some additional notes:

- The link used to create the dynamic link looks like: `https://myapp.com/view/123456`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I suggest, also checking the [debug page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug) to see if it has any warning or errors as this could affect dynamic links behavior

Comment: I am facing exactly opposite where it doesn't open directly to the shared content when first installed from app store but works perfectly fine once installed. Can you help me how you achieve it to work when first installed from app store

Comment: @Nabinda I have the same problem. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @H.P. Yea I did, Actually I was handling the first time open link from [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links)  however once I used initial link as below it was solved
`await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink()`

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly set up your Firebase Dynamic Link domain into your iOS project? Check your iOS app configuration in `Xcode > Targets > Signing & Capabilities > Associated Domains`.

[Check this pages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive)